# How to create pseudo terminal pairs from command line

Tags: bash, pty

I have a Linux application (whose code I have access) which must communicate via serial port with a windows one (third party, no access to code). The windows app runs in Wine, so I want to set Wine's com1 to something and make my software read and write from there. I guess the best way is to use pseudo-terminals, is that so?

Is there a way to simply create a pseudo-terminal pair from command line in Linux? I've already know how to do this using the API, but is there a way to do this from bash?

Maybe with socat or something like it?

Comment: Doesn't socat do what you want?

Comment: I guess so, but do you know how? I don't really know how to use it, but it seems to me that it supposes something already open (like a socket, for instance) and then could create a pty linking both. But what I need are two devices, one to set in Wine, the other in my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use something like this (untested):

```
socat PTY,link=$HOME/.wine/dosdevices/com1,raw,echo=0 PTY,link=$HOME/tmp/dev/myserial,raw,echo=0
```

This will create two back-to-back PTY's which is a bit of overkill, but socat will copy data between them.  The wine program would open one side of the link as COM1, and your program would open $HOME/tmp/dev/myserial to communicate with COM1.

Comment: Hi, Austin. Thank you for your answer, it has put me in the right direction. I still have one further doubt: the data will flow in both directions using the above parameters? In the wine app I can see no data coming, although my linux program receives the output from the windows app.

Comment: Well, the above solution works perfectly. It turns out that the problem was in my windows app, it seems it does not work on wine very well. I tested the command above with two screen's instances (`screen $HOME/.wine/dosdevices/com1` and `screen $HOME/tmp/dev/myserial`) and also with a screen and the linux program in the other end.